# querySelector :scope is null

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I am trying to select a sibling of the current element, but when I use `a.querySelector(':scope')` on the element it is null. When I try to add a sibling selector to the `:scope` it is still null, but if I use it within `.matches(':scope')` it returns true. How can I use the current element within the selector?

```js
let a = document.querySelector('div > a')
console.log(a.querySelector(':scope'))
console.log(a.querySelector(':scope + span'))
console.log(a.matches(':scope'))
```

```html
<div>
  <a href=""></a>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) _"returns the first element that is a **descendant of the element on which it is invoked**"_. [`:scope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope) is the element `.querySelector()` has been called on. Those two combined -> `a.querySelector(':scope')` returns `null` because `a` is not a child of `a`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`querySelector` selects the *descendants* of the context element.

The element itself won't be a descendant of itself, and nor will any of its siblings.

You can use `:scope` if you are targetting a descendant.

For example, to search only the *children* and not deeper descendants you can use `:scope` with the child combinator.

```js
let a = document.querySelector('#foo')
console.log(a.querySelector(':scope > span'))
```

```html
<div id="foo">
 <div><span>2</span></div>
 <span>1</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It's worth adding that the :scope pseudo-class itself is designed to work like querySelector, with scoped selectors matching only descendants of :scope (the scoping root), so a selector like `:scope + span`, while valid, will never match anything regardless of where it's being used (i.e. even in places other than querySelector).

Comment: Googling `js queryselector scope sibling` brought me here, @BoltClock comment is what I was looking for.